# Reading embedded collection from database Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

```
Query queryShift=session.createQuery("select e from employee e join fetch e.calShiftlist");
List<Object[]> listShift=null;
listShift= queryShift.list();
for (Object[] listShift1 : listShift) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listShift1));
}
```

What i get in output is this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: model.employee cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Even when i manage to read data iam getting on output reference on objcet and not gettin real value(string)

```
[model.calShift@602c403c, model.calShift@e2169cd, model.calShift@71808aa4, model.calShift@420c8275,
```

This is my embedded class

```
@Embeddable
public class calShift implements Serializable {

    String shift;

    public String getShift() {
        return shift;
    }

    public void setShift(String shift) {
        this.shift = shift;
    }

}
```

this is how i embedded collections

............

```
.
.
.
@ElementCollection
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
private List<calShift> calShiftlist=new ArrayList<calShift>();
.
. 
.
```

Comment: Well, replace Object by Employee x)

Comment: {Query queryShift=session.createQuery("select e from employee e join fetch e.calShiftlist");
            List<employee> listShift=(List<employee>)queryShift.list();
            
            for (employee listShift1 : listShift) {
                System.out.println(listShift1);
            }} my output is like this : model.employee@645b0177

Comment: That is because objects are printed that way. If you want to have something else as output when your print your employees, overwrite the toString() method in your employee class.

Comment: I had to change toString in my calShift class , tnx verymutch! :D

Comment: @IlijaPavlovic What about the other problem? The classCast exception?

Comment: @Nathan you solved it with<employee>,and then i had problem with showing string, so i had to change toString() method in both classes acctually not only in class calShift. Thank you anyway .

Comment: @IlijaPavlovic I posted it as a proper answer then ^^ Feel free to accept it if you agree with what I put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the database, you're already getting `Employee`s. And you're trying to cast them to an `Object[]`, hence your error.

For the second problem, when you get things like `model.calShift@602c403c`, it comes from the fact that you haven't overriden the `toString` method of your `calShift` class. So the one that gets called is the one from `Object`, which is, as you can see, not really user-friendly.